# React native - How to add option to react native template?

Tags: react-native, react-native-template-typescript

I followed this article and created my own react native template
https://dev.to/roycechua/how-to-make-your-own-custom-react-native-templates-2021-20l5 but I can not control how the project is created when run this command

`npx react-native init someproject --template mytemplate`

My question is: Can I add options to interfere with how the project is created? For example: When initializing with the command `npx react-native init someproject --template mytemplate`, the "is multilang" option can be added and the user can enter Yes (Y) or No (N). The template will then decide whether to install multilang or not based on the user's choice

Comment: It depends on your template code. If your template supports it. It'll work